# Pattern for short circuiting async flows on non-errors in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Node uses the CPS convention for callbacks. Generally in the event a function returns an error the practice is to either handle the error or `callback` the error to your parent by doing something like `return cb(err)`.

The issue I have is that often I need to short-circuit a pathway, but I don't actually have an "error" per-se. Is there an established pattern for doing this?

This issue comes up especially often when using async for flow control.

Here is an example:

```
var primaryFunction = function(arg1, cb) {
    var template;
    var data;
    var result; 

    async.series([
        function(cb) {
            // load some data from different sources
            async.parallel([
                function(cb) {
                    fs.readFile("/somepath", function(err, temp) {
                        if (err) { return cb(err); }

                        template = temp;

                        cb(null);
                    });

                },
                function(cb) {
                    api.find({}, function(err, temp) {
                        if (err) { return cb(err); }

                        data = temp;

                        cb(null);
                    });

                }
            ]
        },
        function(cb) {
            // do a bunch more work

            cb(null);
        },
        function(cb) {
            // do a bunch more work

            cb(null);
        },
        function(cb) {
            // combine data and template
            result = goatee.fill(template, data);

            cb(null);
        }
    ], function(err) {
        if (err) { return cb(err); }

        cb(null, result);
    });
}
```

Lets imagine if the api returns no documents, then I want to halt the flow control so it doesn't run any of the rest of that big async chain, but it's not exactly an error. It's just a short circuit out so maybe I'll put a friendly message on the screen and save myself some processing cycles.

Here are some options I consider:

1. Pass a non-error such as `cb("halt")` and then check `err instanceof Error` in the final callback. The non-null value causes async to not run additional `series`. Then in my final callback I treat "real" errors one way (passing them up), and "my" errors my own way.
2. I could create my own Error type and then return that and `err instanceof MyError` in the final callback. The issue here I've heard creating errors is expensive (certainly more expensive than a string or plain old `{}`).
3. I could create a `next` style callback, but then the system does not play nicely with async and deviates from the CPS standard.
4. I could use promises, since they provide a double callback idea with a success callback and a fail callback, but I'm just not a fan or promises since they aren't as universal as node CPS and there are too many competing implementations.
5. I could set a variable to halt the state, but then I have to check that halt variable in every function in the asyn chain.

Right now, returning simple strings or simple objects seems the best, again this is for intra-module communications not communications that would ever reach outside my module. That solution "feels" dirty, but it technially works. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say this is somewhat (if not much) opinion-based. I personally return strings.

Comment: I would agree, this is entirely opinion-based. I'm just thinking I can't be the only person with this problem and am curious how others are approaching it

Answer (score 0):

I would use option 2 myself.  I'd create a `HaltCondition` error like so:

```
function HaltCondition(reason) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.message = reason;
}
util.inherits(HaltCondition, Error);
```

Then use that as the error parameter in the callback when I need to short circuit the rest of the async flow. I know you're concerned about the expense of creating an error object but, in my experience, it's negligible.

I threw together a quick test and profiled it to see what the difference would be between using the `HaltCondition` error and just returning `true` as the error instead (like your option 1).

This is the code I used (similar to the code in your question):

```
var async = require('async'),
    util = require('util');

function HaltCondition(reason) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.message = reason;
}
util.inherits(HaltCondition, Error);

async.series([
    function(cb) {
        async.parallel([
            function(cb) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    cb(null, 'a');
                }, 10);
            },
            function(cb) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    cb(null, 'b');
                }, 20);
            },
        ], cb)
    }, 
    function(cb) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb(new HaltCondition("test halt"), 'd');
        }, 50);
    },
    function(cb) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb(null, 'e');
        }, 30);
    }
], function(err, result) {
    if (err instanceof HaltCondition) {
        console.log('HALTED:', err.message);
    } else if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR:', err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('DONE:', result)
    }
});
```

I'm halting the async flow in the second series function.

When I was testing it with simply using `true`, I replaced the following lines:

`cb(new HaltCondition("test halt"), 'd');` with `cb(true, 'd');`

and:

`if (err instanceof HaltCondition) {` with `if (err === true) {`

I profiled it in node v0.10.30 using `node --profile` and then processed `v8.log` with [node-tick](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick).

- When using `HaltCondition` the code executed in an average of **93.2 ticks** over 100 runs
- When using `true` the code executed in an average of **93.3 ticks** over 100 runs

An average of 0.1 ticks difference over 100 runs is basically nonexistent (and easily within the margin of error anyway).